# What does the "Mute" Button Do in Apple's AurioTouch2 sample code?

Tags: iphone, audio, buffer, core-audio

I am modifying Apple's code from the AurioTouch2 example on their developer's site. Currently I am trying to fully understand the function of the App. I see that the App writes 0's to the buffers using the silenceData method when mute is on. However, it seems to me that the data has already been processed and when using the App I see no difference wether mute is on or off. What an I missing - what purpose does mute serve?

from the end of performThu method (the input callback)

```
if (THIS->mute == YES) { SilenceData(ioData); }
```

from aurioHelper.ccp

```
void SilenceData(AudioBufferList *inData)
{
    for (UInt32 i=0; i < inData->mNumberBuffers; i++)
        memset(inData->mBuffers[i].mData, 0, inData->mBuffers[i].mDataByteSize);
}
```

[AurioTouch2 Sample Code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch2/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011369-ReadMe_txt-DontLinkElementID_9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I found that the mute button does work. When I hold the phone up to my ear I can hear that the sound from the mic is being played through to the receiver. With mute off there is no sound. Before, I was expecting sound from the speaker (not the receiver). That part of the problem solved.

Second, the remote io unit puts the microphone input data in the ioData buffers. Before I was expecting that there would be another callback for the output to the speaker, but I think because there is not one the remote io unit just uses the same ioData and plays it out the receiver (speaker). Thus zeroing out the ioData (after processing the the microphone input data for use by the app) results in silence at the reciever(i.e. the mute function). Any confirmation or clarification is appreciated.

Comment: Hi...i too have some issues with auriotouch regarding the muite function. Please go through this question,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331327/how-to-mute-the-mics-audio-input-and-recognize-only-the-internal-audio-of-the-d

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, all that's doing is zero-ing out the buffer. The reason it's important, is that it's possible for the `mData` member to be uninitialized (i.e. random), which would result in horribly loud buzzing noises if it was left alone. It's possible that it would make no difference, but you shouldn't really leave that to chance.

If you're ever in a situation where you'd like to produce silence, make sure you 0 your buffer (instead of just leaving it).